# How to combine raster files (.img) into a mosaic and then clip around a boundary?

Tags: gis, raster, data-modeling, arcgis, qgis

I'm new to QGIS and the tutorials I've tried don't seem to be working. Using QGIS 3.10

I downloaded a Lidar DTM package from Ontario GeoHub. I found about 60 files that cover my boundary outline shapefile.

1. I'd like to stitch the raster images together (not overlay) (since I believe you need one raster layer for the next step to clip?)
2. I'd like to clip the raster image to the shapefile outline of a selected area. Aka I want just the raster image to be inside of the boundary-outline shapefile.

I either get a large black square after I try to clip or nothing seems to happen...

https://geohub.lio.gov.on.ca/datasets/776819a7a0de42f3b75e40527cc36a0a?geometry=-82.063%2C43.286%2C-78.117%2C43.982

Comment: This does not seem to be a coding question, and thus not appropriate for this site. You should have more response on https://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question properly, try:

1. Using the 'merge' tool by going to the top toolbar to Raster > Miscellaneous > Merge and putting in all your raster layers
2. Going to the top toolbar to Raster > Extraction > Clip Raster by Mask Layer

As for the large black square, it's hard to know without seeing a minimal example.

Also I just want to second Robert's comment that the GIS stackexchange is a better place for this question.